# Vue.js - how to get specified fields from object via axios reponse data

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

This is my JSON object

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "dani": 5,
    "asset": {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "1",
        "name": "asset1",
        "descr": null,
        "version": "2020-09-01T15:39:53.821+0000",
        "model": {
            "id": 3,
            "code": "4",
            "name": "ZXc43V",
            "descr": "",
            "version": "2020-09-01T15:22:36.953+0000",
            "year": "2020-03-26"
        },
        "location": {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "4",
            "name": "Lokacija 5",
            "descr": "",
            "version": "2020-06-03T12:22:55.693+0000",
            "adress": "Obilicev venac 24",
            "dateFrom": "2020-06-03",
            "dateTo": "2022-05-07",
            "active": false
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I have declared array "assets[]".
What I want to do with it is that when I use

```
axios.get('url').then(response => this.array = response.data
```

I want to extract from my object (which response.data provides) name of asset (asset.name) and put only name of assets in my array "assets[]", so it contains only asset names from JSON objects, and nothing else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` function as follows :

```
this.assets=response.data.map(item=>({name:item.asset.name}));
```

or if you don't need the field :

```
this.assets=response.data.map(item=>item.asset.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried your 2nd option before I posted this question (and I've tried that one again as well as your first option), but I get this error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: item.asset is undefined".

Comment: what's the output of `response.data`?

Comment: Ok, nvm, I had the wrong url in axios request the whole time (lost 2 hours on this)...... it works now (duh). I'm gonna leave this question just in case anyone needs it in the future. Thanks again, you're really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate the object and push into the array.

```
axios.get('url').then((response) => {
  response.data.forEach((item) => {
     this.assets.push(item.asset.name)
  })
})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.